# How to reach services with the URL in Docker-Compose

Tags: docker, networking, docker-compose

Im trying to setup an application environment with two different docker-compose.yml files. The first one creates services in the default network `elastic-apm-stack_default`. To reach the services of both docker-compose files I used the `external` command within the second docker-compose file. Both files look like this:

```
# elastic-apm-stack/docker-compose.yml
services: 
  apm-server:
    image: docker.elastic.co/apm/apm-server:6.2.4
    build: ./apm_server
    ports:
      - 8200:8200
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch
      - kibana
  ...

# sockshop/docker-compose.yml
services:
  front-end:
    ...
    ...
    networks:
      - elastic-apm-stack_default
networks:
  elastic-apm-stack_default:
    external: true
```

Now the `front-end` service in the second file needs to send data to the `apm-server` service in the first file. Therefore, I used the url `http://apm-server:8200` in the source code of the `front-end` service but i always get an connectionRefused error. If I define all services in a single docker-compose file it works but I want to separate the docker-compose files. 
Could anyone help me? :)

Comment: can you ping it? I am not sure (Docker) discovery service can work like this.

Comment: Can you try putting both on same network?

Comment: Is both services on the same machine or you want them too run on different machines? front end doesn't know http://apm-server:8200 when it is running on different network. use loopback instead of service name.

Comment: Yes i can ping it  yes, both services are on the same machine. It works now, i think docker-compose was using old images

Comment: @HectorLorenzo: I need to do the same as you did but I'm stuck. Would you take a look a my question here and see if you can give an answer ? Thanks!! https://stackoverflow.com/q/68240473/11904736

Answer (score 3):

Docker containers run in network `172.17.0.1`
So, you may use url

```
http://172.17.0.1:8200
```

to get access to your *apm-server* container.